# How to put a html attribute in the header of an orgmode file so it applies to all images on export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

To export to html an orgmode file which has links to multiple images, each of which has to have a given width, you can put something like `#+ATTR_HTML: :width 800` above each image.

Is there a way to put this into the header of the file so that it will apply to all images without repetion?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [local file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) in the file (that is a general customization method for emacs, not limited to Org mode). You have to find out the variable that controls that width setting: I do `C-h v org--width TAB` and look at the completions because I can never remember the names. In this case, the correct variable is `org-image-actual-width`: add the following at the *bottom* of your file:

```el
# Local Variables:
# org-image-actual-width: 800
# End:
```

and try the export again. You will need `imagemagick` to be able to change the size of images like this.

Also read the doc string of the variable: there are nuances that the above does not capture - do `C-h v org-image-actual-width RET`.